# Google play console error app develop in Flutter : This release does not add or remove any app bundles

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, google-play-console-beta

I created new fresh google play console account, I upload first(1) version of my flutter app, so the app need some changes when I do that changes in it and uploaded second version of app then I face that error: "This release does not add or remove any app bundles.". I do some functionality modification in app, and also modify the Version of app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSVRi.png)